# How to Subtract 2 Arrays and Sum the difference in one Cell?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

This is an example of what i want to achieve;
So i have two arrays need to subtract them and check if the array in the right has all the values if not i don't want to subtract the empty cell with the correspondig cell in the other array (example {B3-D3})
and i want to add the sum of all the differences in A5.
My previous solution was to do on column E

```
E1=ifnumber(D1),B1-D1 
E2=ifnumber(D2),B2-D2 
E3=ifnumber(D3),B3-D3 
E4=ifnumber(D4),B4-D4
```

But I'm looking for something more elegant that shows the result using only one cell in this case A5

[image: Example]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In A5:

```
=SUM(FILTER(ABS(B1:B4-D1:D4),ISNUMBER(D1:D4)))
```

Comment: Your answer is saying #ERROR!. don't understand why bit thank you for your answer.

Comment: As player0 has suggested, there is no way for us to know why an error is occurring unless you share a copy of your sheet with us. However, it's possible that you are in a region where the formula element separator is a semicolon rather than a comma. If so, replacing the comma with a semicolon will fix it: =SUM(FILTER(ABS(B1:B4-D1:D4);ISNUMBER(D1:D4)))

Comment: Fantastic that was the problem it has worked. I'm fairly new using Google sheets and you guys tought me loads. Thank you. The google sheet I was working has sensitive data therefore won't be sharing it. Cheers!

Comment: Glad the solution was simple. Would you please mark the answer as the "Accepted" answer. It will make it easier for future users to find solutions; and it lets other volunteers here know that the issue has been resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try in A5:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(B1:B4-D1:D4)))
```

Comment: Your answer works but it's adding the empty cells. Is there a way to overcome that? Tried SUMIF instead of of SUM but I get an #ERROR!.

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?